# How to avoid generating all subsequences

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Square Subsequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000226/square-subsequence)

I have been trying to solve the "[Square Subsequences](https://www.interviewstreet.com/challenges/dashboard/#problem/4f3067592a7be)" problem on interviewstreet.com:

> A string is called a square string if it can be obtained by concatenating two copies of the same string. For example, "abab", "aa" are square strings, while "aaa", "abba" are not.
>
> **Given a string, how many subsequences of the string are square strings?**

I tried working out a DP solution, but this constraint seems impossible to circumvent: `S will have at most 200 lowercase characters (a-z)`.

From what I know, finding all subsequences of a list of length `n` is **`O(2^n)`**, which stops being feasible as soon as `n` is larger than, say, 30.

Is it really possible to systematically check all solutions if `n` is 200? How do I approach it?

Comment: Please could you link the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, for every letter `a..z` you get a list of their indices in `S`:

```
`p[x] = {i : S[i] = x}`, where `x = 'a',..,'z'`.
```

Then we start DP:

```
S: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            ^          ^    ^
            r1        l2    r2
```

Let `f(r1,l2,r2)` be the number of *square subsequences* (subsequences that are square strings) of any length `L` such that

1. `SS[L-1] = r1`
2. `SS[L] = l2`
3. `SS[2L-1] = r2`

i.e. the first half ends exactly at `r1`, the second half starts exactly at `l2` and ends at `r2`.

The algorithm is then:

Let `f[r1,l2,l2] = 1` if `S[r1] = S[l2]`, else 0.

```
for (l2 in 1..2L-1 )
    for( r1 in 0..l2-1 )
        for (r2 in l2..2L-1)
            if( f(r1, l2, r2) != 0 )
                for (x in 'a'..'z')
                    for (i,j: r1 < i < l2, r2 < j, S[i] = S[j] = x) // these i,j are found using p[x] quickly
                        f[i, l2, j] += f[r1, l2, r2]
```

In the end, the answer is the sum of all the values in the `f[.,.,.]` array.

So basically, we divide `S` unisg `l2` into two parts and then count the common subsequences.

It's hard for me to provide exact time complexity estimation right now, it's surely below `n^4` and `n^4` is acceptable for `n = 200`.

Comment: Thanks. I also found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10036622/1488067) in the meantime, so I will check its complexity. I don't have enough rep (`>=15`) to upvote right now.

Comment: @Dilbert, yeah, good, I think that answer has exactly the same idea, but it omits the 'how to efficiently find pairs of equal letters in given segments' part: I use `p[x]` for this purpose, you can even use binary search in `p[x]`. And the second: that solution has one more dimension to the array: the start of the first sequence, which seems unnecessary to me: it multiplies the time and space complexity on `n` one more time, making this pessimistically (which I don't believe, it's too rough) `n^6`.

Comment: @Dilbert, ok, `n^4` now.

Comment: +1 But 200^4 is not that small IMHO. Time limit is 5s for C#, and doing a single multiplication 200^4 times on my 1.6Ghz Core2duo takes around 8s, so even if it would pass their test, it would be a pretty close shave. I believe there should exist a lower time complexity solution.

Comment: @Dilbert, yep, there's a `n^3` solution, maybe I'll edit later. You should've stated the time limit in the question.

Comment: Thanks, no sweat, this works. I haven't submitted it yet, but it returns same results as a brute force method. However, for the last step, I used the other mentioned answer to prepare all character pairs first and created jump tables to avoid checking the entire alphabet. However, (on my machine) it still takes ~7 seconds for a string of length 110 (containing a single repeating character, which is the worst case). [This page](http://lyanalgorithm.blogspot.com/2012/02/square-subsequence-now-12th.html) also describes a DP algorithm (vaguely), but I don't understand the recurrence at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are many algorithms (e.g. [Z-algorithm](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/3107)) which can in linear time generate an array of prefix lengths. That is for every position i it tells you what is the longest prefix that can be read starting from position i (of course to i = 0 the longetst prefix is n).

Now notice that if you have a square string starting at the beginning, then there is a position k in this prefix length array such that the longest length is >=k. So you can count the number of those in linear time again.

Then remove the first letter of you string and do the same thing. 
The total complexity of this would be  O(n^2).

Comment: But note that the question is asking for subsequences, not substrings. For example, `baba` contains 3 square subsequences (`baba`,`bb`,`aa`).

Comment: Also it was an interview, sure no one expect from someone else to implement Z in interview.

Comment: interviewstreet.com is not an interview lol

Comment: :-) Yeah you  are right.